# Installing wxPython, choosing an installation folder

Tags: ide, wxpython, installation, default, anaconda

This is a very obvious beginner question (I presume):

I'm installing wxPython on windows 8, and I'm wanting to choose the right installation folder. Now, I was using Canopy as my IDE, but I recently downloaded Anaconda and like that better.

The default install folder that it wants to go in is:
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages

1. Should I install it somewhere in the Anaconda directory?
   C:\Anaconda\ ... ? (... Lib\site-packages\, maybe?)
2. I'm guessing there's also some 'default IDE' sort of thing I should change in order to make Spyder my default IDE

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following:

```
conda install wxpython
```

According to this [thread](http://wxwidgets.10942.n7.nabble.com/WxPython-Build-and-install-is-there-a-simple-way-td85300.html), that should work.

Otherwise, if Anaconda has its own Python folder, then you'll want to install wxPython to that folder as well. When I use Python on Windows, I just install Python to `C:\Python27` and then all packages are also installed into this location under its `site-packages` sub-folder. Since Anaconda doesn't appear to use this folder hierarchy, then you will almost certainly need to install wxPython inside Anaconda's folder hierarchy.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Installing things is the bane of my existence.

oi58.tinypic.com/qyeiqa.jpg